# Actions must have a type property error NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have simle effects class that have to get some data from Firebase and dispatch a new action.

```
@Injectable()
export class TripsEffects {

     constructor(private actions$: Actions, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {}

     @Effect()
     loadTrips$ = this.actions$.ofType(TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS)
         .pipe(
             switchMap(() => {
                 return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
                     map(user => new LoadTripsSuccess(user))
                 );
            })
         );
}
```

But I get error `Actions must have a type property`. When user logs in, they are redirected to Trips page and in Trips component i am dispatching an action to load trips. Here are my actions :

```
export enum TripsActionsTypes {
    LOAD_TRIPS = '[Trips] Load Trips',
    LoadTripsSuccess = '[Trips] Load Trips Success',
    LoadTripsFailure = '[Trips] Load Trips Failure'
}

export class  LoadTrips implements Action {
    type: TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS;
}

export class  LoadTripsSuccess implements Action {
    type: TripsActionsTypes.LoadTripsSuccess;
    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class  LoadTripsFailure implements Action {
    type: TripsActionsTypes.LoadTripsFailure;
    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that you need to change from `type: ...;` to `type = ...;` in your action definitions.

`type: TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS;` means `type` property is of type `TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS`

`type = TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS;` means that `type` is instantiated to the value of `TripsActionsTypes.LOAD_TRIPS`.

So the type property on your actions is never being initialized. It is an easy mistake to make because the object literal syntax uses `:` for initialization (ex: `{ type: 'something' }`) and typescript doesn't give you a transpilation error for it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That was the issue

Comment: Very Good Observation! Yes, I spent two days and I could not fix this, I was making the same mistake.